# How to access struct and enum members form a class?

Tags: c++, struct, enums

This seems to be a trival question with an easy solution but it has been a problem for me for some time. What I'm talking about is this piece of code:

```
class MainWindow
{
    public:

        enum class Difficulty
        {
            Beginner,
            Intermediate,
            Advanced
        };

        struct DifficultyLevelsProperties
        {
            struct BeginnerProperties
            {
                const int PADDING_HEIGHT = 9;
                const int PADDING_WIDTH = 9;
                const int MINES = 10;
            };

            struct IntermediateProperties
            {
                const int PADDING_HEIGHT = 16;
                const int PADDING_WIDTH = 16;
                const int MINES = 40;
            };

            struct AdvancedProperties
            {
                const int PADDING_HEIGHT = 16;
                const int PADDING_WIDTH = 40;
                const int MINES = 99;
            };
        };

        MainWindow();
        ~MainWindow();

    private:

        Difficulty difficulty = Difficulty::Beginner;
        int mines = DifficultyLevelsProperties::BeginnerProperties.MINES;
        int paddingHeight =  DifficultyLevelsProperties::BeginnerProperties.PADDING_HEIGHT;
        int paddingWidth = DifficultyLevelsProperties::BeginnerPropertiesPADDING_WIDTH;
```

What I am trying to achieve is pretty obvious. I tried many combinations using "." and "::" operator in different places or making them static, but still I just can't get it right. I either get "'Difficulty' is not a class or namespace" error or "expected primary-expression before '.' token". Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Please post the code that is causing the errors, as well as where in the project and what files contain it. Are you using header files correctly? Are you certain you don't need forward-declaration? Your nested types are public, which is a code-smell; are you certain you want to use a nested-type instead of a top-level type?

Comment: I think you should be using an array of instances for `DifficultyLevelsProperties` instead of separate `struct` definitions, as they have the same structure.

Comment: Your class is missing a closing `}` and `;`. This is not the code that you're having trouble with. Post real code.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your advice, by the way very helpful but I am looking for a solution to my problem! I don't know what you mean by your second comment @Dai, could you explain or demonstrate it by an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I am looking at into your code is that you are trying to access a value that is not instantiated. I mean, when you try to assign a value to `mines` attribute, you are referencing the declaration, but not the value instantiated, because nothing is instantiated.

When you declare something, you are explaining how the memory is going to be structured without assign any value or behaviour.

The enumeration is working because the symbolic name is mapped into a value (old times it was mapped directly into an int type), so when you reference the symbolic value you don't get an error. This is different into `mines`, `paddingHeight` and `paddingWidth`. The code below is working for me:

```
class MainWindow
{
    public:

        enum class Difficulty
        {
            Beginner,
            Intermediate,
            Advanced
        };

        struct DifficultyLevelsProperties
        {
            struct BeginnerProperties
            {
                const int PADDING_HEIGHT = 9;
                const int PADDING_WIDTH = 9;
                const int MINES = 10;
            } beginner;

            struct IntermediateProperties
            {
                const int PADDING_HEIGHT = 16;
                const int PADDING_WIDTH = 16;
                const int MINES = 40;
            } intermediate;

            struct AdvancedProperties
            {
                const int PADDING_HEIGHT = 16;
                const int PADDING_WIDTH = 40;
                const int MINES = 99;
            } advanced;
        } levelProperties;

        MainWindow();
        ~MainWindow();

    private:

        Difficulty difficulty = Difficulty::Beginner;
        int mines = levelProperties.beginner.MINES;
        int paddingHeight = levelProperties.beginner.PADDING_HEIGHT;
        int paddingWidth = levelProperties.beginner.PADDING_WIDTH;
};
```

By the way, the design maybe is not the best from the point of view of SOLID principles. You are mixing handling the properties with the MainWindow. Maybe is better extract that feature from the MainWindow.

Happy coding for your minesweeper ;)

Comment: Wow, that was helpful! Thank you very much! Well, it was a silly error.
Anyway, could you explain your last two sentences? Not sure if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Hmmm... I still get "'Difficulty' is not a class or namespace" error... ideas?

Comment: I had to compile with the modifier `--std=c++11`, maybe you have to specify that.

Comment: This is about SOLID principles.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

Maybe this other link is more didactic:

https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design

Comment: Yep, I forgot -std=c++11 flag, that's it. Thank you very much for the links! And for the solution!